# Mutual TLS on apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-dsl

In Camel's examples doesn’t have any example or documentation for mutual TLS.

How to setup the mutual tls setup in both **java dsl** and **spring dsl** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the camel point of view you'll be targeting a https resource if you are acting as a client or serving it if you are the service. The mutual authentication is handled at the network layer so Camel won't have explicit hooks.

In the case of the client add the keystore/truststore (with the required certs added) to the startup commands `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\temp\clientkeystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\temp\truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password`

The additional flag `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` is useful for debugging ssl handshake

For a server (assuming Spring boot) enable ssl as follows, again with the required certs added to it's keystore

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=C:\\temp\\serverkeystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.trust-store=C:\\temp\\trustStore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=password
server.ssl.client-auth=want
```